# Getting the first key in a multidimensional array with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, extract

I have a multidimensional array called `$test`:

```
Array (
    [First item] => Array (
        [screen] => 2
        [1] => 2
        [2] => 2
        [3] => 2
        [4] => 2
    )
    [Second Item] => Array (
        [screen] => 3
        [1] => 3
        [2] => 3
        [3] => 3
        [4] => 3
    )
)
```

I am trying to get the keys: `screen`, `1`, `2`, `3`, and `4`.
They are the same for `First item` and `Second item`. Do you know how I can loop through this array to get those values? So, basically getting the keys for the first array in my multidimensional array. Thank you!

Comment: Or `foreach ($arr as $key => $val) { $key; \\ something... }` maybe? I'm not sure what you want to do with the keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you are trying to archive:

```
$test = Array (
    "First item" => Array (
    "screen" => 2,
        1 => 2,
        2 => 2,
        3 => 2,
        4 => 2,
    ),
    "Second Item" => Array (
    "screen" => 3,
        1 => 3,
        2 => 3,
        3 => 3,
        4 => 3,
    )
);
```

**To get all the keys**

```
$vals = [];
foreach($test as $k=>$v){
    $vals = array_merge($vals, array_keys($v));
}
```

this will yield you:

```
Array
(
    [0] => screen
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 3
    [4] => 4
    [5] => screen
    [6] => 1
    [7] => 2
    [8] => 3
    [9] => 4
)
```

**Separated in another multidimensional array:**

```
foreach($arr as $k=>$v){
    $vals[] = array_keys($v);
}
```

**Only the unique keys:**

```
foreach($test as $k=>$v){
    $vals = array_unique(array_merge($vals, array_keys($v)));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
$keys = array_keys($test['First item']);
```

Or if you want to do it manually:

```
$keys = array();
foreach($test['First item'] as $key => $value) {
    $keys[] = $key;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That would be something like:

```
$keys = array_keys(reset($your_array));
```

[`reset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php) gets the first value of your array and [`array_keys()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) the keys of the resulting array.

You might want to split it in two lines using a temporary variable to avoid strict warnings.